# Sharepoint 2010 and SQL server 2012 in separate servers, need to use powerview

Tags: infrastructure, powerview, sql-server-2012

I am trying to setup a reporting environment and would like to use powerview features. Can someone let me know if this will work?
Install sharepoint 2010 in a separate web server
Install SQL server 2012 in a separate server
both servers will be connected via network
will I be able to use powerview using this setup?

or do I have to install sharepoint and SQL server in the same server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you sure will. This is how it is expected to work on a real production environment. In this scenario though authentication becomes more complex as SharePoint needs to impersonate the users and send their credentials to the SQL Server instance running on a separate server. This is often called double-hope authentication. You can find more information [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg502594.aspx). This is also a good [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219068.aspx) for the preparation and installation process.